# Cannot locate message "MultiArrayLayout" in python ROS bag API

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

I get the following error message when parsing a bag file with rosbag API when there is a message of type Int16MultiArray: "Cannot locate message [MultiArrayLayout]: unknown package [std_msgs] on search path [{}]."

Here is the code to parse the bag:

```
import roslib; roslib.load_manifest('rosbag'); roslib.load_manifest('std_msgs'); 
from std_msgs.msg import Int32, String, Int16MultiArray 
from std_msgs.msg import MultiArrayLayout, MultiArrayDimension 
for topic, msg, t in bag:   
    #do stuff here
```

As you can see, I include the type that I need (Int16MultiArray) and also it's subtypes (MultiArrayLayout and MultiArrayDimension), but I still get the error.  Below is some stack trace.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "PowerTransferSensorPositionAnalysis.py", line 163, in <module>
    main()
  File "PowerTransferSensorPositionAnalysis.py", line 53, in main
    for topic, msg, t in bag:
  File "/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosbag/bag.py", line 2062, in read_messages
    yield self.seek_and_read_message_data_record((entry.chunk_pos, entry.offset), raw)
  File "/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosbag/bag.py", line 2198, in seek_and_read_message_data_record
    msg_type = _get_message_type(connection_info)
  File "/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosbag/bag.py", line 1309, in _get_message_type
    message_type = genpy.dynamic.generate_dynamic(info.datatype, info.msg_def)[info.datatype]
  File "/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/genpy/dynamic.py", line 151, in generate_dynamic
    for l in msg_generator(msg_context, spec, search_path):
  File "/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/genpy/generator.py", line 725, in msg_generator
    genmsg.msg_loader.load_depends(msg_context, spec, search_path)
  File "/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/genmsg/msg_loader.py", line 344, in load_depends
    return load_msg_depends(msg_context, spec, msg_search_path)
  File "/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/genmsg/msg_loader.py", line 313, in load_msg_depends
    depspec = load_msg_by_type(msg_context, resolved_type, search_path)
  File "/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/genmsg/msg_loader.py", line 119, in load_msg_by_type
    file_path = get_msg_file(package_name, base_type, search_path)
  File "/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/genmsg/msg_loader.py", line 78, in get_msg_file
    % (base_type, package, search_path))
```

Thanks for the help

Edit: I should also note that the same error happens when opening the bag with rxbag.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/58015/cannot-locate-message-%22multiarraylayout%22-in-python-ros-bag-api/) by [amittleider](https://answers.ros.org/users/2448/amittleider/) on ROS Answers with karma: 227 on 2013-03-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [btakac](https://answers.ros.org/users/3406/btakac/) on 2013-04-02**:
Hello! I have a very similar problem, with the same traceback. On Fuerte on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.  Final msg: MsgNotFound: Cannot locate message [Header]: unknown package [std_msgs] on search path [{}]
Is there known solution?

**Comment by [amittleider](https://answers.ros.org/users/2448/amittleider/) on 2013-04-07**:
I still have not found a solution (but haven't been looking too hard).  It is quite an annoying problem for me.. I had to hack the feature in for now by converting them to a string, publishing, then parsing the string on the other side.

**Comment by [PeterMilani](https://answers.ros.org/users/3621/petermilani/) on 2013-06-21**:
Are you using ROSJAva, I get this error for messages published from ROSJava nodes. I am thinking to implement a cpp node to rebroadcast these messages to rosbag and see if it makes a difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A workaround if you are having problems with [ROSJava messages and rosbag](http://code.google.com/p/rosjava/issues/detail?id=158),
Is to write an efficient cpp node that subscribes to the ROSJava messages you want to store and republishes on topics to rosbag using a roscpp publisher.
I had been getting similar errors using Rosbag to subscribe to ROSJava messages. This allowed me to save my ROSJAVA message traffic in a bag file.

Hope this helps

---

Originally posted by [PeterMilani](https://answers.ros.org/users/3621/petermilani/) with karma: 1493 on 2013-06-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [amittleider](https://answers.ros.org/users/2448/amittleider/) on 2013-08-11**:
Thanks.  This definitely fixes the problem, but it seems odd that rosbag and rosjava don't work well together when rospy and rosjava work perfectly fine.  I implemented this fix for all of my *MultiArrayLayout messages.  The other message types in std_msgs work without the fix.

**Comment by [Teny](https://answers.ros.org/users/2405/teny/) on 2013-11-21**:
Could you guys explain how to fix this? I have several bag files that have some topics subscribed from android ros. I think it's matter of ROSJava but have no idea how to fix it. It there any way to fix the bag files to see on rqt_bag or rxbag? I'm a very beginner.